# Why I don't get the context of the virtual printer?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, printing, gdi+

Windows 8.1 x64

I have installed [PdfCreater](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator) virtual printer. It is the default printer (and single) on my computer.

Now I want to get its context:

```
HDC GetPrinterDC(void)
{
    PRINTER_INFO_5 pinfo5[3];
    ZeroMemory(pinfo5, sizeof(pinfo5));
    DWORD dwNeeded, dwReturned;
    if (EnumPrinters(PRINTER_ENUM_DEFAULT, NULL, 5,
        (LPBYTE)pinfo5, sizeof(pinfo5), 
        &dwNeeded, /* I get 0 */
        &dwReturned /* I get 0 */)) {
        // And I am here...
        return CreateDC(NULL, pinfo5[0].pPrinterName, NULL, NULL); // NULL
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I get `NULL`. Why does it happen?

Comment: That's not how you create a printer context.  Google "windows create printer context" and take the first hit.

Comment: This code is from the Petzold's book (chapter 15). It gets the default printer context.

Comment: If that was copied verbatim from Petzold's book, Petzold is incorrect. You must call `EnumPrinters` to get the necessary buffer size before calling it to get actual results.

Comment: I added the `ZeroMemory(pinfo5, sizeof(pinfo5));` line and the comments in the Petzold's code ("Programming Windows 95").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do error check on the result of the first `EnumPrinters` (Petzold doesn't do it either)

Note also, the amount of required memory could be several hundred bytes for 1 printer. But `PRINTER_INFO_5 pinfo5[1];` may allocate less than that. So you have to allocate what the first `EnumPrinters` call tells you.

```
HDC printerDC = NULL;
DWORD flags = PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL;// | PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS;
DWORD memsize, printer_count;

//figure out how much memory we need
EnumPrinters(flags, NULL, 5, NULL, 0, &memsize, &printer_count);
if (memsize < 1) return;

//allocate memory
BYTE* bytes = new BYTE[memsize];

if (EnumPrinters(flags, NULL, 5, bytes, memsize, &memsize, &printer_count))
{
    if (printer_count > 0)
    {
        PRINTER_INFO_5* printerInfo = (PRINTER_INFO_5*)bytes;
        printerDC = CreateDC(NULL, printerInfo->pPrinterName, NULL, NULL);

        //optional, list printer names
        for (UINT i = 0; i < printer_count; i++)
        {
            OutputDebugString(printerInfo->pPrinterName);
            OutputDebugString(L"\n");
            printerInfo++;
        }
    }
}
delete[] bytes;
```

If you want to access default printer, another option is to use `PRINTDLG` (without actually showing any print dialog)

```
PRINTDLG pdlg;
memset(&pdlg, 0, sizeof(PRINTDLG));
pdlg.lStructSize = sizeof(PRINTDLG);
// Set the flag to return printer DC, but don't show dialog
pdlg.Flags = PD_RETURNDEFAULT | PD_RETURNDC;

PrintDlg(&pdlg);
printerDC = pdlg.hDC;
```

see also 
[How To Print a Document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/139652)
[How To: Retrieve a Printer Device Context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 for the `PrintDlg` technique. Although it's a heavyweight function as compared to doing it yourself, you're pretty much guaranteed to always get a correctly constructed `DC` even if Microsoft were to change the underlying API.

Comment: I would recommend passing the variable to the `sizeof` operator. When you later change the code to use a different structure it remains valid (or fails to compile, if you change the variable name as well). Either way, you won't introduce subtle bugs. While not currently an issue with this particular API, there are others that take different structures (e.g. `BITMAPINFOHEADER`/`BITMAPV4HEADER`/`BITMAPV5HEADER`). It's just a defensive strategy that helps to write more maintainable code.